# share.php tag and facebbok

Tags: facebook, meta

Hello everyone I use share.php
obviously `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2Fid.php%3Fid%3D13` to the Reference link I put the appropriate destination but  at first click of facebook does not show it the title it 's image According to the click of the link is working around

ps i cant use api it is impossible for me to have a key

Answer (score 1):

No need for an API key, Facebook uses [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started) to get this data so all you really need to do is place the `og:meta` tags into the source HTML of the page you are sharing:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of content"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Type of content"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site Name"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/id.php?id=13"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/img/image.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Description of this content"/>
```